# How can I read and carry out an user command from the console (stdin) while main loop is running in Gstreamer?

Tags: c, io, gstreamer, glib

I can stream a video, but also I want to get user commands from the console (stdin) and carry out the command while streaming the video. For example, if user enters a text 'exit' to command line, I want it to quit from the loop. I can do it by creating my own thread but there must be a more clever way to do it in Gstreamer.

I use fdsrc to read from stdin and fakesink to printout the command as following:

```c
...
userInput = gst_parse_launch("fdsrc ! fakesink dump=true", error);
gst_element_set_state (userInput, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
/* start streaming. the default port for RTSP streaming is 8554. */
g_print ("stream is ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test1\n");
g_main_loop_run (loop);
gst_object_unref (userInput);
return 0;
...
```

But I do not know how to get the text entered by the user into a function. I feel like I need to use a callback function but fdsrc or fakesink does not have a callback function.

How can I get and process the text entered by the user while g_main_loop is running?

Comment: You should check [this example](http://docs.gstreamer.com/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=327794). See the part for setting up `io_stdin`.

Comment: suggest running the gstreamer functionality in a thread.  then the main can  be looking for input from the user and set some common variable that the thread can be checking.

Answer (score 3):

Create a [`GIOChannel`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html) for `stdin` and attach it to your `GMainLoop`. It will be added in to the main poll loop for your program, and a callback (provided by you) will be called each time input is available on `stdin`. As long as GStreamer is using the same `GMainLoop` then they should run together without blocking each other, and without the need for you to explicitly run your GStreamer code in a separate thread.

See this gist for an example of using `GIOChannel` to receive and handle command line commands: https://gist.github.com/bert/260094/c099d4535694d91992a87e04864a3c05134afa3e